# How to create routing with Angular 1 and TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'am new in TypeScript, and I can not find example for routing. 
Help me.
Thanks.

Comment: This question is pretty broad, are you using modules or are you using namespaces. If you are using modules what module format are you using and what loader or packager are you using?

Comment: I ask because I have an answer for each different approach.

Comment: If it is not a problem, .Answers to both. I'am new in TypeScript.

Comment: I'll try to post some this afternoon on my lunch break. I have examples for namespaces, AMD modules, and System.register modules. The other answer takes care of the webpack/commonjs module side of things. Which router are you using? You are using? ui-router or ng-route?

Comment: I using ng-route.

Comment: I added some commentary and exposition to my answer that I hope you will find helpful. I attempted to put it into some context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of setting up your router configuration using angular-route (***ng-route***), TypeScript and ES Modules via SystemJS

**configure-routes.ts**

```
import { ILocationProvider, route } from 'angular';

import homeTemplate from 'home/template.html';
import HomeController from 'home/controller';

import usersTemplate from 'home/template.html';
import UsersController from 'home/controller';
import UserService from "./services/user-service";

configureRoutes.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
export default function configureRoutes(
  $routeProvider: route.IRouteProvider,
  $locationProvider: ILocationProvider
) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
      template: homeTemplate,
      controller: HomeController
    })
    .when('/users', {
      template: usersTemplate,
      controller: UsersController,
      controllerAs: 'usersController',
      resolve: {
        users
      }
    })
    .otherwise('/');

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

  users.$inject = ['UserService'];
  async function users(userService: UserService) {
    if (!userService.isAuthenticated) {
      throw Error('unable to resolve, route not loaded');
    }
    return await userService.get();
  }
}
```

**services/user-service.ts**

```
import { IHttpService } from 'angular';

export default class UserService {
  static  $inject = ['$http'];
  constructor(readonly $http: IHttpService) { }

  async get() {
    const { data } = await this.$http.get('api/users');
    return data as User[];
  }

  get isAuthenticated() {
    return true; // stub
  }
}
```

**users/controller.ts**

```
import { User } from 'models';

export default class UsersController {
  static $inject = ['users'];
  constructor(readonly users: User[]) { }
}
```

**users/template.html**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(name, id) in usersController.users">{{name}}: {{id}}</li>
</ul>
```

**models.ts**

```
export interface User { id: number, name: string }
```

**app.ts**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import ngRoute from 'angular-route';
import UserService from 'services/user-service';
import configureRoutes from "./configure-routes";

const app = angular
  .module('app', [ngRoute])
  .service({
    UserService
  })
  .config(configureRoutes);

export default function bootstrap(element: Document | Element) {
  return angular.bootstrap(element, [app.name], { strictDi: true })
}

export const __useDefault = true;
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
  <script src="jspm.config.js"></script>
  <script>
    SystemJS.import('app')
      .then(function (app) {
        app.bootstrap(document.body);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  </script>
</body>
```

As stated this uses TypeScript, ng-route, and SystemJS, but i think it is worth noting that most of it is not specific to these choices, even in how they relate to AngularJS.

There are only seven (11) instances of TypeScript specific syntax and they correspond to (6) type annotated parameters, (2) parameter property shorthand via `readonly`, a (1) *type assertion* on the result of the http service call, and (2) static property initializers that have not yet been voted into the ECMAScript standard. Remove these and you have a 100% standards compliant ECMAScript 2017 program.

There is one piece of SystemJS loader specific machinery visible, the `__useDefault` export, which is actually completely optional and shown here for convenience and exposition. Remove it, or ignore it, and another loader could technically be used.

Finally all of the calls to `$routeProvider.when` can be replaced with `$stateProvoder.state` ((1) $inject would need to be updated as well) with no changes to their arguments and the app would work with `ui-router`.

Therefore as I read over it, I'm not entirely sure I actually answered the question asked. I basically provided an example of an opinionated AngularJS app organizational pattern that I find  works very well in practice.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it with ng-annotate-webpack-plugin:

routes.ts:

```
export default function Router($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider) {
    'ngInject';
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            template: require('./modules/mainWindow/app.html'),
            abstract: false
        })
        .state('app.state', {
            url: '/state',
            template: require('./modules/state/index.html')
        })
        .state('app.state.nestedState', {
            url: '/nestedState',
            template: require('./modules/state/nestedState/index.html')
        })
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app');
}
```

app.ts :

```
    //imports
    import Router from './router';
    //other code
    angular.module(MODULE_NAME,
    [/*dependencies*/])
    .config(Router)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have an example in GitHub or or somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: How can I get data that is resolved in route into the controller?